# can't get data via gen_udp

Tags: sockets, erlang, udp

i run `tcpdump -i eth0 -vv ip6` on remote server and see such packets

```
11:10:36.712804 IP6 (hlim 1, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 103) fe80::f816:3eff:fe94:a348.57100 > ff3c::8500:2345.57100: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 95
```

but when i open Socket

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(57100, [binary, {active, true}, {ip, any}, inet6, {reuseaddr, true}])
```

or

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(57100, [binary, {active, true}, {ip, any}, inet6, {multicast_ttl, 225}, {multicast_loop, false}, {reuseaddr, true}])
```

or

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(57100, [binary, {active, true}, {ip, {65340,0,0,0,0,0,34048,9029}}, inet6, {multicast_ttl, 225}, {multicast_loop, false}, {reuseaddr, true}])
```

`{65340,0,0,0,0,0,34048,9029} = <<"FF3C:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:8500:2345">>`

and waiting for message in such way

```
subscribe_on_stream() -> 
    %% {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(57100, [binary, {active, true}, {ip, IP}, inet6, {multicast_ttl, 225}, 
    %% {multicast_loop, false}, {reuseaddr, true}]), 
    {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(Port, [binary, {active, true}, {reuseaddr, true}]), 
    io:format("self: ~p line: ~p~n", [self(), ?LINE]), 
    subscribe_loop(Socket). 

subscribe_loop(Socket) -> 
    receive 
       Any -> 
           io:format("~p~n", [Any])
    end.
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more code? Where is the `receive ... end.` placed?

Comment: `subscribe_on_stream() ->
%%  {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(57100, [binary, {active, true}, {ip, IP}, inet6, {multicast_ttl, 225},
%%    {multicast_loop, false}, {reuseaddr, true}]),
  {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(Port, [binary, {active, true}, {reuseaddr, true}]),
  io:format("self: ~p line: ~p~n", [self(), ?LINE]),
  subscribe_loop(Socket).

subscribe_loop(Socket) ->
  receive 
    Any ->
        io:format("~p~n", [Any])
end.`

Comment: @ipinak i didn't make mistake with getting res in other process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't add multicast group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376640/cant-add-multicast-group)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the `subscribe_loop(Socket)`. It's not actually looping. You call the function once, it returns and that's it. You need to call `subscribe_loop(...)` recursively to do a loop.

Here is an example of how to write a very simple server waiting for messages.

https://www.erlang.org/course/concurrent-programming

Solution:

```
subscribe_loop(Socket) -> 
    receive 
       Any -> 
           io:format("~p~n", [Any]),
           subscribe_loop(Socket)
    end.
```

Comment: mm. no. if your meaning was right i will get at least one message, but i don't

Comment: the problem is that i don't get at least one message

Comment: You are right, you have to receive at least one message before it dies. I just ran that exact same code and it worked for. So there is something else going on. Check your firewall maybe you have denied access to erlang.

Comment: yes, problem is much deeper. will do my best to solve it

Comment: do you have experience with listeting multicast? i think maybe problem is that i send it in wrong way
gen_udp:open(57100, [binary, {active, true}, {ip, {65340,0,0,0,0,0,34048,9029}}, inet6, {multicast_ttl, 225},
    {multicast_loop, false}, {reuseaddr, true}])

Comment: I don't know a lot about multicast, only some basic stuff. You can try to listen to a multicast address using this `{multicast_if, Address}` and take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851061/listening-for-ipv6-multicasts-on-linux

Comment: i succesfully listened on ipv4, but some troubles with ipv6. answer is there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376640/cant-add-multicast-group?noredirect=1#comment64166721_38376640